# How to exit 'git-cmd.exe' after running a command via it in a batch file?

Tags: ruby, windows, git, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file that runs a command via `git-cmd.exe` but it doesn't run the command(s) after it.

I've tried to use `CALL`, `START /WAIT`, and `START /B /WAIT`. All have the same behavior. Maybe there is a parameter should be sent to `git-cmd.exe` to execute the command and exit but I didn't find any guide explaining how to use `git-cmd.exe`.

This is a sample batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "PATH=C:\Ruby26-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;%PATH%"
SET "CurrentDirectory=%CD%"
CD /D "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_*\"
SET "GitDirectory=%CD%"
CD /D "%CurrentDirectory%"
"%GitDirectory%/git-cmd.exe" CALL rake build
PAUSE
```

The command passed to `git-cmd.exe` is executed but the `PAUSE` command doesn't execute until I type `EXIT` command manually in the 'Command Prompt' window.

I've also tried a simple `DIR` command instead of `rake build` but the same issue still occurs:

```
"%GitDirectory%/git-cmd.exe" DIR
PAUSE
```

Comment: Try `EXIT` in the command line: `"git-cmd.exe" "DIR; EXIT"`

Comment: @phd the `;` doesn't work. I think it's parsed as a parameter to `dir` command. However, `"git-cmd.exe" "DIR & EXIT"` or `"git-cmd.exe" "DIR && EXIT"` works but this doesn't work with `rake build` command as it needs `call` before it to exit. Even if after adding it to be `"git-cmd.exe" "CALL rake build && EXIT"`, it doesn't work (`EXIT` is not executed).

Comment: Thanks all, the issue has been resolved. I'll add the resolution as an answer.
There was a conversation here between me and someone else (I think mony) but all his comments has been deleted, don't know why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions, the issue was resolved by passing `EXIT` command to `git-cmd.exe` as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "PATH=C:\Ruby26-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;%PATH%"
SET "CurrentDirectory=%CD%"
CD /D "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_*\"
SET "GitDirectory=%CD%"
CD /D "%CurrentDirectory%"
"%GitDirectory%/git-cmd.exe" "CALL rake build & EXIT"
PAUSE
```

There was a useful conversation between me and someone else (I think his name was mony) but it was deleted, don't know why?!
He sent me this link with the difference between `&` and `&&` between commands:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/9586127

The `&` before the `EXIT` command in order to execute both commands independent on result of the first one. If `&&` is used, the `EXIT` command will be executed only if the first command succeeded (exit code 0).

In addition, he told me a way to replace the lines 3:6 by one line to be:

```
FOR /D %%I IN ("%LocalAppData%\GitHub\PortableGit_*") DO SET "GitDirectory=%%I"
```